# Imprimindo ticket com Flutter (problema com imagem)

Tags: flutter, dart, impressora

Recebi uma demanda para implementar um modo de impressão via app Flutter de tickets, no entanto estou com dificuldade em imprimir as imagens, pois ou quebram ou travam na impressão, no momento esta assim meu código:

"Future ticket(NetworkPrinter printer, dynamic ticket) async {

```
printer.qrcode('AS465da5', size: const QRSize(5));

printer.hr();

String texto = 'INTEIRA';
int larguraLinha = 24;
int espacosAdicionais = calcularEspacosAdicionais(texto, larguraLinha);
String linhaFormatada =
    ' ' * (espacosAdicionais ~/ 2) + texto + ' ' * (espacosAdicionais ~/ 2);

printer.text(
  linhaFormatada,
  styles: const PosStyles(
    align: PosAlign.center,
    height: PosTextSize.size2,
    width: PosTextSize.size2,
    reverse: true,
  ),
);

printer.feed(2);

final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/times/vamosla.jpg');
final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
final image = decodeImage(bytes);

if (image != null) {
  final int targetWidth = 175;
  final resizedImage = copyResize(image, width: targetWidth);
  printer.imageRaster(resizedImage);
}

printer.feed(2);

printer.text('Time1 X Time2',
    linesAfter: 0, styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center));
printer.feed(2);
printer.text('Local: Local',
    linesAfter: 0, styles: const PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left));

printer.feed(2);

printer.qrcode('AS465da5',
    size: const QRSize(3));

final ByteData data2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/times/saneago.jpg');
final Uint8List bytes2 = data2.buffer.asUint8List();
final image2 = decodeImage(bytes2);

if (image2 != null) {
  final int targetWidth = 75;
  final resizedImage2 = copyResize(image2, width: targetWidth);

  printer.imageRaster(resizedImage2);
}

printer.feed(2);
printer.cut();
printer.reset();
```

}"

Ao inserir apenas uma imagem ou apenas um QRCode vai tudo ok, no entanto quando adicionar mais uma imagem começa a dar problemas [Segue a imagem com erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oryuY.jpg)